# LDAP Get pre Win2K Logon name

Tags: ldap

I want to query all user by group from LDAP, and get the pre Windows 2000 logon name to user for comparison with an external data.

My code is:

```
public GroupPrincipal GetGroup(string groupName)
{
    var principalContext = GetPrincipalContext();

    var groupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, groupName);
    return groupPrincipal;
}

public List<AdGroupMember> GetGroupMembers(string groupName)
{
    return (from member in GetGroup(groupName).GetMembers()
        let sad = member.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry
        let membreUpn = member as UserPrincipal
        select new AdGroupMember
        {
            MemberName = member.SamAccountName,
            RoleName = groupName,
            DomainName = member.UserPrincipalName ?? member.SamAccountName + "@" + member.Context.Name,
            UserGuid = member.Guid.HasValue ? member.Guid.Value.ToString() : new Guid().ToString(),
            FirstName = membreUpn.GivenName,
            LastName = membreUpn.Surname,
            Email = membreUpn.EmailAddress,
            Tel = membreUpn.VoiceTelephoneNumber,
            Title = membreUpn.GetProperty("title")
        }).ToList();
}
```

But the result is not return to me the logon name in format MYDOMAIN\User, but User@MYDOMAIN.com

For example, I have a user: crmadmin1, I want to get CRM2015\crmadmin1, which is pre win2K logon name, but I can only get crmadmin1@crm2015.constoso.com.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could anyone please help? It is very urgent. Thank you so much.